# Unit Vector Perpendicular to Given Vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I understand there are questions on the Math Exchange already, but upon analyzing them I have still not figured out how to solve my own problem.

My problem is to find all vectors that are perpendicular to the vector $(1, -2, 5)$, have the y-components be equal to 3 times the x-components, and have a length of 5.

I know that the first step is to set the dot product of my vector and another vector equal to zero. And the result is $i-2j+5k=0$, correct?

After that my method falls apart as I am trying to find ***ALL*** vectors perpendicular to my vector. Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your first equation is correct. Any vector satisfying that will be perpendicular to your given vector. Now create equations for the other conditions and solve.

Comment: Despite the title you’ve given this question, the problem doesn’t want you to find a unit vector.

Comment: You do realize that there’s an infinite number of vectors perpendicular to $(1,-2,5)$, yes? It looks like you’ve picked out just a single solution to the first equation that you formulated. The probability is zero that it happened to be the right one.

Comment: @amd I believe my answer below is sufficient, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hint.
The thing is, you need *all* prependicular vectors.

Start with all vectors possible, let's designate them $(x;y;z)$.
Now choose all vectors that are perpendicular to your vector $0 = (1; -2; 5) \cdot (x;y;z) = x -2y + 5z$.
This gives you one equation.
The other two are $y = 3x$ and $5^2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$.
Solve the equations and you'll get the result.

Comment: Would solving this require a system of equations?

Comment: @ThatOneNerdyBoy , yes. We can call 3 equations a system. But in this case the system is quite simple. I can add a full solution for you if you feel need.

Comment: I solved it and got x = sqrt(25/11), y = 3sqrt(25/11), and z = sqrt(25/11). Does that seem right?

Comment: @ThatOneNerdyBoy You should have at least two solutions.

Comment: @ThatOneNerdyBoy , looks good for me. But there is one more solution to this system of equations. Try vector directed just opposite to the one you found.

Comment: @amd and guest Oh silly me, the negative would also work just fine! Thanks!